# Symfony 3.4 : "Could not load type ... : class does not exist"

Tags: symfony-2.8, symfony-3.4

Sorry, I'm a beginner at Symfony and I've tried to find an answer but nothing worked. I'm using Symfony3.4 which was updated from Symfony 2.8 a few months ago.

Now, I'm trying to do a rather simple thing : using a formType in a Controller, but no matter what, Symfony keeps showing the following error : **Could not load type "Cha\GeneralBundle\Form\StripePaymentType": class does not exist.**

Here's my StripePaymentType -really, really basic:

```
namespace Cha\GeneralBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class StripePaymentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cha_stripe_payment_form';
    }

}
```

Here's my Controller action, once again, a basic thing (I didn't even write any code in there, because of this strange error) :

```
public function upgradeOfferPaymentAction(Offers $offers)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(StripePaymentType::class);


    return $this->render(
        '@ChaGeneral/Offers/offer_payment.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I tried to use my form as a service but it did not work either :

```
cha.stripe.payment.form:
    class: Cha\GeneralBundle\Form\StripePaymentType
    tags:
        - { name: cha_stripe_payment_form }
```

I'm probably missing something but I can't figure what...

Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show your "use" statement in your controller.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I should have posted it before :

use Cha\GeneralBundle\Form\StripePaymentType;

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. I'd ask you to post the path to your form class but Symfony would throw an error if the file path didn't match the class name.

Comment: It's indeed throwing the same error if I use $form = $this->createForm('Cha\GeneralBundle\Form\StripePaymentType'); .

Comment: Try to change your form's class name. Symfony should throw an error saying that the class and file name don't match. If that's not the case, it might mean that Symfony isn't parsing the file at all.

Comment: You seems to be right, if I change the class name, it's still throwing the same error: 

Could not load type "Cha\GeneralBundle\Form\Manala": class does not exist.

Why do you think Symfony is not parsing this file? All the other formType in this directory are functionning.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was to rename your class into the file StripePaymentType.php, not in your controller. Symfony should throw an error before anything else, even if you try to clear the cache using the console.

If Symfony throws this error, it means that the class autoloading works correctly. If not, the file is not parsed.

Comment: Same result, Symfony doesn't throws another error :/

Comment: That's weird.
No error in the file extension ? I remember wasting hours because my file was named .phpp a few weeks back...
It might have to do with your upgrade process but i can't help you there since i started with 3.4. If you post the content of your services.yaml file someone else might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying. The file extension is correct, sadly the full services.yml file is enormous (especially since the project has 8 differents bundles with they own enormous services.yml file), I guess I could came from anywhere.

Comment: If i were you i'd start out by doing a lot of cleanup in your services configuration. As you're certainly aware, most of this configuration is useless since Symfony 3.3 now handles dependency injection. Getting rid of a maximum of useless configuration might make this (as well as future problems) easier to pin down.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You must add this line at the top of the form class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
```

Revert the SF version is not a solution, is just dodge the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found what caused this problem : somebody did a composer update and we updated from Symfony 3.4.13 to Symfony 3.4.14. A simple revert did the trick, now everything is working again.

Thanks a lot for your help!